# Don`t show short description on a single page

Tags: posts

Is any way to don`t display shrort description in a single entry page?

It is necessary to be able to write any text, then paste the tag "more". This content should be displayed only on the list of records page. But it should not be displayed on the single entry page.

Comment: How are you showing content? `the_content()` will show the full content on single pages.

Comment: @DaveRomsey Exactly, I use the_content();

Comment: Since you are already using `the_content()` then It would be better if you show some code of your. how we can offer any suggestion without seeing any code?

Answer (score 0):

`the_content()` will show the full content on single pages even if there is a `<!--more-->` tag present.

On archive pages, only the excerpt will be shown, provided that a `<!--more-->` tag is present.

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite get your question but his worth a try, if I am understanding you. Add this function to your functions.php or a related file

```
function get_excerpt2($count){
  $permalink = get_permalink($post->ID);
  $excerpt = get_the_content();
  $excerpt = strip_tags($excerpt);
  $excerpt = substr($excerpt, 0, $count);
  $excerpt = substr($excerpt, 0, strripos($excerpt, ""));
  return $excerpt;
}
```

And then return this code in your template with desired number of characters in the function.

Full code in this gist https://gist.github.com/bahiirwa/d773a50708fbd25a3b5f98823a2a296b